# How to test whether atleast one item has be dropped on JQuery UI Droppable?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have a div that is 'designated' as droppable: `$( "#droppable_div" ).droppable`.

On the other hand, I have multiple draggable divs that are made draggable by assigning a CSS class which has been designated as draggable: `$(".draggable_css").draggable`.

Now, both these are in a form. So, when I submit a button, I need to test whether atleast one of the draggable items/divs have been dropped on the droppable div.

Can someone please suggest how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the number of child of your droppables div.

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kn7uF/

And the code :

```
<div id="droppable_div1"></div>
<div id="droppable_div2"><div id="find-me"></div><div id="find-me"></div></div>

<script>
    alert("There are "+$( "#droppable_div1 > #find-me" ).size()+" elements in the droppable_div1")    
    alert("There are "+$( "#droppable_div2 > #find-me" ).size()+" elements in the droppable_div2")
</script>
```